# Laravel validation rule for exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation

I am trying to add a validation rule for a menu.

```
$table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
```

A link could have a **parent_id** or **NULL** for level 0.

```
'parent_id' => 'sometimes|exists:links,id'
```

I want to apply the "exists" rule only if **'parent_id'** is set (fixed by **sometimes** rule) and if **parent_id** is different than **0** or **null**.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: Thanks but actually I need something like "exists_unless:parent_id,0", I am using "sometimes" instead of "required if"

Comment: So how about required unless?

Comment: You can extend the validator and implement custom rules if you like.